# SOQL Query : Get a list with records, only if the record MAX(CreatedDate) is not succesful

Tags: soql, query, max

We have a custom object with interface logs and I would like to get a list of only the last record for a certain entitiy (e.g. contacperson), only is this last record is nog succesful. If the last record for that specific entity is succesful, I don't need that record in my list.
However, I have a query what shows the last unsuccesful record for a contactperson, regardless is there is an newer interface log which is succesful.
How can I get a list of the last interface logs, which are only not succesful.
This is the code I had:
`SELECT msf__Person__c, MAX(CreatedDate) FROM msf__Interface_Log__c WHERE msf__Successful__c = false GROUP BY msf__Person__c`

Anyone idea if this is possible within SOQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice question actually. Not easy to do but I believe it is possible using 'HAVING' on SOQL. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm

I don't have an org with the right setup and data to verify this, but basically you:

- don't want to filter on msf_Successful__c = false, because you also need 'true' in order to filter out the ones you don't need
- need to order by CreatedDate (descending) so the latest one for each group of person is on top
- then filter those based on whether the top one (=latest one) is not successful
- (including the record Id in the query result is optional)

This would result in a query like this, showing you only the id/person where the latest created one is not successful:

```
SELECT MAX(id), msf__Person__c, MAX(CreatedDate) , MAX(msf__Successful__c) 
FROM msf__Interface_Log__c 
GROUP BY msf__Person__c 
HAVING MAX(msf__Successful__c) = false 
ORDER BY MAX(CreatedDate) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  At HAVING MAX(msf__Successful__c) = false I got the error that MAX() was not compatible with a true/false field, so I addes a formula field that was filled with the creation date, if succesful was true. 
So the query now is:
SELECT MAX(id), msf__Person__c, MAX(CreatedDate) , MAX(SC_Date_succesful__c)
FROM msf__Interface_Log__c 
GROUP BY msf__Person__c 
HAVING MAX(SC_Date_succesful__c) = NULL
ORDER BY MAX(CreatedDate) DESC
And this worked!

Comment: Ah, nice workaround indeed :-)